# WCF net.tcp binding client type

Tags: wcf, client, net.tcp

I have WCF service with net.tcp binding. Visual Studio create CLIENT in Windows can connect, get proxy and it works!

Now I am interested how can connect from other OS's, for example from:

- iOS
- Android
- MacOS
- Linux

Comment: You won't be able to connect via NetTCP with non-Microsoft platforms.  You'll need to use one of the *HttpBindings.

Comment: @Tim you might be able to with Mono but yes, NetTcp is .Net only

Comment: Thanks ,and what is Mono?

Answer (score 0):

Mono is, put pretty bluntly, an open-source, cross platform .NET. It could be very well a good solution to connect from non-MS platforms as Tim mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `netTcpBinding`, but you can use `basicHttpBinding` and best is to use WebAPI.

Reference link
http://www.asp.net/web-api

Hope this will help !